# Mercedes 190 Automatic gearbox won't shift up

Tags: transmission

My Mercedes 190 is experiencing a problem where it seemingly won't shift up through the gears. If I attempt to accelerate past ~30mph the engine revs rise but the car doesn't accelerate (like clutch slip).

The car has a GA-type transmission.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to tell from the limited information we have here but I'd check the transmission fluid levels and condition first and assuming that they are fine (if you find the ATF fluid is black, or contains metal chips then the 'box has in technical terms "had it" and will need reconditioning or replacement) then move on to the vacuum line to the modulator and if that checks out then it could be the modulator itself that has failed.

There's an outside chance that it *could* be the K1 spring kit issue but that affects the shift from 2nd to 3rd which if you are only getting up to 30mph sounds unlikely to be the culprit here.